# Are some cognitive bias universal? If yes, which one?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, bias

Many studies show that humans are subject to “cognitive bias” such as the loss aversion or, ingroup vs outgroup, or negativity bias.

These studies often claim that the cognitive biases are universal among humans (that all humans have the tendency to be affected by the bias), but most of these studies are run on westerners.

I’m thus looking for bias that has really been proved to be universal based on studies run on people from different origins/culture.

The only study I found, coming close to my requirement has tested the “hot hand bias” (or “winning streak effect”) in American undergraduates and Shuar hunter–horticulturalists from Ecuador.  (The conclusion that the “hot hand bias is universal” is only based on 2 populations, 32 students at UCLA and 32 Shuar hunter-horticulturalists)

(Wilke, A., & Barrett, H. C. (2009). The hot hand phenomenon as a cognitive adaptation to clumped resources. Evolution and Human Behavior, 30(3), 161-169.)

Comment: Hi Loly. Your question was closed for being to broad. As you can see from the votes you got it is a very interesting one. Perhaps you could specify it to a particular (subset of) cognitive bias(es). That would make the question easier to answer :)